# Extract MySQL Query using Regex

Tags: php, mysql

I want to extract query and separated to array like this 
[image]

My problem is i need `[from => account_admin]` and have `[join => ['LEFT JOIN account_admin_role_relation ON account_admin.id = account_admin_role_relation.admin_id', 'LEFT JOIN account_admin_role ON account_admin_role_relation.admin_role_id = account_admin_role.id']]`

This is my progress :

```
$query = '
    SELECT account_admin.id, account_admin.name, email, account_admin_role.name AS role FROM account_admin
    LEFT JOIN account_admin_role_relation ON account_admin.id = account_admin_role_relation.admin_id
    LEFT JOIN account_admin_role ON account_admin_role_relation.admin_role_id = account_admin_role.id
    WHERE status = 1
    GROUP BY account_admin.id
';

$matches = null;

$regex_value = '(?:\w++|`[^`]*+`|"(?:[^"\\\\]++|\\\\.)*+"|\'(?:[^\'\\\\]++|\\\\.)*+\'|\s++|[^`"\'\w\s])*?';
preg_match('/^\s*(?:\bSELECT\b\s*(' . $regex_value . '))?(?:\bFROM\b\s*(' . $regex_value . '))?(?:\bWHERE\b\s*(' . $regex_value . '))?(?:\bGROUP\s+BY\b\s*(' . $regex_value . '))?(?:\bORDER\s+BY\b\s*(' . $regex_value . '))?(?:\bLIMIT\b\s*(' . $regex_value . '))?(?:;|$)/si', $query, $matches);

$parts = array_combine(['query', 'select', 'from', 'where', 'group', 'order', 'limit'], $matches + array_fill(0, 7, ''));

if (preg_match_all('/(LEFT|INNER|OUTER|RIGHT)?\sJOIN((?:(?!\sJOIN).)+)/i', 'FROM ' . $parts['from'], $matches)) {
    $parts['join'] = $matches[0];
}

if (preg_match('/FROM\s+(.+)/i', 'FROM ' . $parts['from'], $matches)) {
    $parts['from'] = $matches[1];
}

print_r($parts);
```

Edit : I just looking for simple array as output because i just working with simple query select .. from .. join .. where .. group .. order .. limit

Comment: In case you feel like you're reinventing the wheel here (you really are IMO) https://github.com/greenlion/PHP-SQL-Parser/blob/master/wiki/Parser-Manual.md

Comment: Writing a SQL parser that doesn't misbehave when there're subqueries, comments or string literals is a daunting task (serve as circumstantial evidence that Packagist [doesn't list many](https://packagist.org/search/?tags=parser&q=%2Bsql%20%2Bparser) and most of them are probably unmaintained forks of the one recommended by Calimero).